VB.NET Regex.Replace not working (array not updating)
It must be a really silly error that I just can't see here... or my recent switch from .NET Framework to .NET8 plays tricks on me. I'm simply trying to get rid of HTML tags in an array of strings, and whilst debugging I see that my variable "l" gets updated properly, i.e. the Regex itself works. But the line isn't updated in the array.
Would someone please point to my error? Thank you ever so much!
Here's my code:
Private Function RemoveHTMLTags(content As String) As String()

    Dim lines() = content.Split(vbLf)
    For Each l In lines
        l = Regex.Replace(l, htmlRegexG, String.Empty)
        'l = ... more changes here
    Next
    Return lines

End Function

EDIT: Just to avoid confusion, htmlRegexG is defined as string "<\w>|</\w>" outside the method and it does change the variable!

The documentation says that you cannot modify the elements themselves in a For Each...Next loop. Any modification you make affects only the local copy from Current and isn't reflected back into the underlying collection:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement

@Anna Thank you for the link – the information given there is so detailed that I understand the difference now!

You could update line(i) instead of l:
Private Function RemoveHTMLTags(content As String) As String()
    Dim lines() = content.Split(vbLf)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        lines(i) = Regex.Replace(lines(i), htmlRegexG, String.Empty)
        'lines(i) = ... also modify the other changes
    Next
    Return lines
End Function


I've just tried it and it works – thank you very much! I just don't comprehend the difference, as both methods loop through the array of lines/strings, don't they? Considering Anna's remark, either both or neither one should work.

@Mick No, the changes of ls are not reflected back in the lines() array.
